# Ruby on Rails 3 - creating plugins or engines with views and controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines

I've just started my RoR programming, and I want to create plugin / engine with its view and controllers for my simple rails app. I've found tutorial about creatng plugins on the official rails wiki but unfortunately it is for rails 2 :(

So, how can we write plugin with views and controllers for RoR 3 app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails 3 makes it really easy to achieve this. Actually, once you declare your gem as an Engine, it will look automatically in all the basic folders: `/app`, `/public`, ...

I'd suggest you have a look at [this github project](https://github.com/krschacht/rails_3_engine_demo) which is an Engine framework.

You'll be able to build your own using this example.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the best way is to use Josè Valim's Enginex gem:

https://github.com/josevalim/enginex

it lets you to easily create a gem skeleton for a rails engine. it also creates a *dummy app* for tests (supports both rspec and Test::Unit).

Also, Enginex will be the default plugin generator for the upcoming rails 3.1 (actually is rc4).

Comment: Enginex is fine when you know how to build gems but it's not dedicated to learn. Not that really adapted for a first shot. That's well illustrated in the book 'Crafting Rails Apps' where Jose Valim uses his gem BUT still needs to configure almost everything.

Comment: I've read that book and I used enginex to create a gem. I've also created a gem *manually* and it was a pain. the concepts behind a rails engine are simple enough, the hard part is packaging and testing.